# how to decoder this json format ( that i never seen. )

Tags: json, format, decoder

usually we will see json in this format

```
{"query":"google.com","domain":"google.com","domain_idna":"google.com","host":"","subdomain":"google.com"}
```

and then to decoder we will use

```
                 $server = $server_url_for_requests_json_response;
                 $json = @file_get_contents($server, true);
                 $decode = json_decode($json, true);
                 $domain_idna = $decode[domain_idna];
```

and then we will get `$domain_idna = google.com;`

but now i get this json format ( that i never seen. )

```
{"status":"success","domain":"google.com","available":false}
```

i want to get   /// available /// how can i decoder

to get this json click here http://freedomainapi.com/?key=3xhebruryp&domain=google.com

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is it the `false` that's confusing you?

Comment: see
{"status":"success","domain":"google.com","available":false}

object available , false not have "  "

Comment: Both are valid JSON. Read up on JSON here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: can you decode
{"status":"success","domain":"google.com","available":false}
and get available value